# on click live multiple triggers

Tags: jquery, onclick

At the moment I have this:

```
$(this).on('click', '.like_count_y', function(e)
```

I want this to be triggered on several clicks of different class names, but it wouldn't work. How can I achieve something like:

```
$(this).on('click', '.like_count_y .secondclass .thirdclass', function(e)
```

Comment: @mplungjan Why "try" ? This is the answer.

Comment: @dystroy when I do this it wouldn't work

Comment: @Nikola Please build a fiddle and show us (here) the HTML. There's not enough code here to be sure.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, commas were the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add commas to separate class names:

`$(this).on("click",'.like_count_y, .secondclass, .thirdclass', function(e)`

And/or go the other way around

`$('.like_count_y, .secondclass, .thirdclass').on("click", function(e)`

Comment: Yes, that is my mistake, I will accept this answer as soon as I can :-)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get different classes include in the scope, you should separate them with comma in the second parameter, like:

```
$(this).on('click', '.like_count_y, .secondclass, .thirdclass', function(e){...});
```

Comment: Why do you bother adding an answer identical to a precedent one ?

Comment: well, in his defense, it isn't identical, it's just the same answer. possibly got here before the previous answer was posted.

Comment: It wasn't yet posted when I submitted mine, otherwise I wouldn't do it, of course. Better twice that none, anyway. Thanks Kevin.